# JavaFX application looks different when runs from OSX app bundle (on retina display)

Tags: java, macos, javafx

So I've got a JavaFX application. It works and looks absolutely fine on my MacBook Pro with retina display. Now I'm trying to create a native OSX bundle to distribute my application. This bundle contains JAR with my application and JRE 1.8 itself inside (I'm using `appbundler-1.0.jar` form oracle.com in my build.xml to create the bundle).

But the thing is that when I run absolutely the same application from .app bundle it looks different from application runned via `java -jar myapp.jar`. It seems like application from bundle ignores the HiDPI settings and just stretches the UI so it looks... grainy, pixels are too big. And even doc icon looks very bad.

Here is the image to illustrate the problem:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13089585/jfx-app-bundle-problem.png

How can I fix this problem? Is there any JVM option to tell javafx not to ignore HiDPI?